# Convex combination of $1$ point inside a triangle

Tags: analysis, convex-analysis

Given $(1,0),(-1,3),(-2,1)$, express a point $(x,y)$ in the interior of the triangle as a convex combination of the vertex.

Attempt:

I suppose I should take a point inside the triangle, let's say $(-1,1)$ and then to express it as a convex combination.

My question is how should I introduce the vertex in the convex combination?

I have the form of a convex combination $x=\sum\lambda(-1,1) , \lambda\ge0$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Guide:

Suppose $(x,y)$ is fixed in the interior, you goal is to determine $a,b,c$ such that

$$(x,y) = a(1,0) + b(-1,3)+c(-2,1)$$

$$a+b+c=1$$

Now, we have $3$ equations and $3$ unknowns.

Comment: Actually you need to assume $a, b,c > 0$

Comment: Yes, if it is in the interior, it will be satisfied by default.

Comment: 3 equations? I just see a pair of coordinates $(a-b-2c,3bc)$ and $a+b+c=1$

Comment: Can you express $a-b-2c$ in terms of $x$ and $y$?

Comment: hmm it would be just in terms of x? $x=(a-b-2c)$

Comment: Great, count that as $1$ equation.

Comment: oh I see..thanks